# How to user modernizr to detect canvas support

Tags: modernizr

All I want to do is detect Canvas support in the browser. Modernizr's "Documentation" page is a thousand lines long, but doesn't seem to be able to explain feature detection simply (its main function), and rants about polyfills instead. Anyway, this:

```
Modernizr.canvas
```

Simply returns `undefined` instead of `true` or `false`. How can I get Modernizr to actually tell me if this feature exists in the browser or not?

Answer (score 1):

Modernizr doesn't report `false` when things are not supported. It only reports `true` if they are, simply letting the fact that unsupported properties are undefined act as falsey value.

In the Firefox I'm on, for instance, `Modernizr.canvas` reports `true`. On an old Android version, it reports `undefined`, which in a conditional is equivalent to `false`:

```
if (Modernizr.canvas) {
  // do canvasy things
} else {
  // notify users that you need canvas, and their browser won't work
}
```

It does this for everything: if supported, it'll be true. If not, it'll not actually a property on the Modernizr object, and so calling will make the JS engine report `undefined` as per the JavaScript specs.

Comment: Erm that actually sounds like a bug. Modernizr casts all detect results to `true` or `false` — although there may be some exceptions. Which version are you using?